# regex pattern for max length 12

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex pattern where the max length is 12 and it should not accept 0 if entered by user.

My current pattern is not working. Here it is:

```
[0-9]{0,12}
```

any suggestions is welcome and also the explanation of the pattern.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use Regex for making sure user doesn't provide 0 in input? Because that makes the expression complex.

Answer (score 2):

`^[1-9]{0,12}$` means up to 12 digits (excluding 0), left emtpy is allowed.

If this field is required, you could change the minimun to 1, `^[1-9]{1,12}$`

And by the way, `^` and `$` means start and end of the input string.

If your regexp is `[1-9]{1,12}`, without `^` and `$`, then `"abc123def"` is allowed because the center part `123` is matched.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found my answer "^[1-11]$"

Comment: @THOMAS are you sure? `/^[1-11]$/.test("123")` is `false`. And it doesn't look like a legal regexp.

Answer (score 0):

I have not Exact Solution Of you Problem But I Can Give **HINT**

1 For  MAX length You Can Use **\d{MIN,MAX}**

In  Your Case 
**EX \d{12}**

2 Only Allow 1-9 Digit You can Use **^([1-9]?)$**

[1-9] is set Which Allow Only Digit which Falls in this set

You can Check This http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think following Regex should serve your purpose

```
^[1-9]\d{0,11}$
```

It will accept all your normal use cases just that user will be expected to enter string without leading 0. So 12345 will be accepted but not 012345.

Comment: I think the above pattern is not working. even when i enter value greater than 0 it is showing message that this should be greater than zero. Right now im entering value 5 with maxlength set at 20

Comment: Please try that regex in http://regexpal.com/ and let me know whether it highlights the value showing a match or not? For me entering 5 did hightlight it indicating a match.